# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'model_.B' not found in RandomForest function

Tags: r, random-forest

```
$ price                       : int  11200 27000 16000 12750 14500 14900 16000 16250 14250 14250 ...
 $ transmission                : Factor w/ 3 levels "Automatic","Manual",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ mileage                     : int  67068 14827 62794 26676 39554 35309 38538 10401 42668 36099 ...
 $ fuelType                    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Diesel","Electric",..: 1 4 1 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 ...
 $ tax                         : int  125 145 160 145 160 125 125 145 30 20 ...
 $ mpg                         : num  57.6 42.8 51.4 72.4 50.4 60.1 60.1 52.3 62.8 68.9 ...
 $ engineSize                  : num  2 2 3 1.5 3 2 2 1.5 2 2 ...
 $ automaker                   : Factor w/ 4 levels "BMW","Ford","Mercedes",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age                         : int  8 4 6 5 8 6 5 4 5 6 ...
 $ model_.1.Series             : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.2.Series             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ model_.3.Series             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.4.Series             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ model_.5.Series             : int  1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ model_.6.Series             : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.7.Series             : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.8.Series             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.A.Class              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.Auris                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.Avensis              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.Aygo                 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.B-MAX                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.B.Class              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.C-HR                 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.C-MAX                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ model_.C.Class              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Hello! I used the dummy function to separate the levels of factors of my original variable named "model". Then I am trying to do random forrest prediction.(i have fixed the spaces for the column names using gsub). Then I am setting the training and the testing.

```
n_rows <- nrow(my_final_cars)
training_idx <- sample(n_rows, n_rows * 0.7)
training_my_final_cars <- my_final_cars[training_idx,]
test_my_final_cars <- my_final_cars[-training_idx,]
```

But when I try the following I get an error at the train function

```
my_final_cars_formula <- reformulate(names(training_my_final_cars[, -1]), response = 'price')

ctrl_parameters <- trainControl(method = 'CV', number = 5)

modelLookup('rpart')

my_final_cars_tree <- train(my_final_cars_formula, data = training_my_final_cars, method = "rpart", trControl = ctrl_parameters)


my_final_cars_tree
```

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'model_.B' not found
```

model_.B I am 100% sure that it doesnt exist in my dataset. Do you know why it happens to tell me that it doesnt find a variable that shouldnt be found from the moment that there isnt something named like this in my dataset? Do you have any suggetions?

Comment: There's a non-standard name in R, normally (interactively) it would need to be referenced as `my_final_cars[["model_.B-MAX"]]` (double-`[` and quoted) or `my_final_cars$\`model_.B-MAX\`` (backticked). While I don't see you using it here, that suggests that something else is not referencing it well and safely internally. Try changing the names of that and your two `C` variables that also contain a hyphen/dash in them.

Comment: Could you please explain this more? Because there are lots of column with similar names. If I understood well, you suggest to change each of them that gets this error manually?

Comment: or just change the - to _?

Comment: It seems this is the problem r doesnt recognise - + etc. Thanks a lot for your respnse your help was accurate and on the point

Comment: A dash `-` in a column/variable name is generally not preferred, and will require that you deal with it specially. An underscore does not have that problem. In your frame, you have three names that have a dash/hyphen. If you change those hyphens to underscores, it should work.